# Regrouping fields in list

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a C# app that manages schools, I have class "classroom" which contains a list of students List, each student has a  list of posts... I want a property in the class "classroom" that returns all the posts in this class. Is there a linq query or method that could do this?

```
internal class Classroom
{
    private string classId;
    private List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    private int Students_nbr { get => Students.Count; }

    public List<Post> All_Posts { get; set; }//gets all posts from all students
}

internal class Student
{
    private int student_id;
    private string first_name;
    private string last_name;
    private List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

internal class Post
{
    private int post_id;
    private string title, content;
}
```

Comment: probably yes, but where is your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the SelectMany operator, most likely.

This could be a method in your class:

```
IEnumerable<Post> Posts => StudentsList.SelectMany(student => student.Posts);
```